# What part of JavaScript code fires strange request?

Tags: javascript, debugging, xmlhttprequest, breakpoints

Take a look at this site **http://tinyurl.com/xhrexample** and

- pick a size in the select box titled "Vælg størrelse"
- push the "LÆG I INDKØBSKURV" button

Now 3 requests are fired

1. POST cart.actions.php
2. GET /produkter/(...)
3. GET /kurv/?forajax

I have 2 questions:

1. I wonder where the second event comes from. XHR Breakpoints in Chrome does not break on the 2nd event. This is a customization of an existing system, so I don't know everything about how it is constructed.
2. Sometimes (in unlucky cases?) not all requests are made. This is very hard to debug - any ideas?

Comment: I'm considering using some kind of jQuery AJAX request queue library to solve my second question. Any recommendations? I have looked at https://gist.github.com/1039247 and 
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the POST request causes a response with code `302 Found`. A `Location` header is sent along redirecting to another page, namely `/produkter/...`, which is therefore the second request made. This resource, in turn, contains the following JavaScript code on line 308:

```
getCart("#MiniCartContents", "http://askepotsko.dk/kurv/?forajax", ...);
```

which makes for the third request.